# Should I use "Does" or "Is" in this question?

Tags: word-choice

Does vs Is?

> Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of brilliance or ignorance?

In this sentence what would work best?

Answer (score 17):

### Short answer

You should use *is*.

---

### Long answer

First, let's look at a basic (declarative) clause:

> [Presenting yourself confidently]<sub>subj</sub> **is** [a sign of brilliance]<sub>comp</sub>

This is called a **copular clause**.  In this kind of clause, we use a form of the verb *be* to link a subject to its complement.  The word *copular* means 'linking', and the English verb *be* is the copula, used to link subjects to complements.

In particular, this is an **ascriptive copular clause**<sup>1</sup>, in which the complement tells us something about the subject ("ascribes" a property to the subject).  We need a form of *be* for this to work.

The verb *do* cannot be used for this purpose:

> <sup>#</sup> [Presenting yourself confidently]<sub>subj</sub> **does** [a sign of brilliance]<sub>comp</sub>

I've marked this sentence with a <sup>#</sup> symbol to show that it doesn't make any sense.  The verb *do* is not the copula, and with *do* the sentence is nonsensical.

Things get a little more complicated when we consider forming a question.  To form the sort of question you're asking about, we need an auxiliary verb to swap places with the subject.  The verb *be* works great for this, as it has its own special grammar: *be* is almost always an auxiliary verb, even without any following main verb, and so we can form a question by inverting it with the subject in this example:

> [Presenting yourself confidently] **is** a sign of brilliance. 　←　*statement*
>   **Is** [presenting yourself confidently] a sign of brilliance?　←　*question*

*Do* can be an auxiliary verb too, but as an auxiliary it requires a following main verb.  Even if we wrote the declarative version with *do*, we wouldn't be able to invert it the way you suggested:

> <sup>#</sup> [Presenting yourself confidently] **does** a sign of brilliance.　←　*nonsensical statement*
>   ***Does** [presenting yourself confidently] a sign of brilliance?　←　*ungrammatical question*

*Does* here can't be an auxiliary because there is no following verb, and so it can't invert, which means *does* is both nonsensical and ungrammatical in this position.

To make it grammatical, we would have to add the auxiliary *do* and invert that.  In the following example, the first *do* (in the form *does*) is an auxiliary, while the second *do* is a lexical verb<sup>3</sup>:

> <sup>#</sup> [Presenting yourself confidently] **does do** a sign of brilliance. 　←　*nonsensical statement*
>   <sup>#</sup> **Does** [presenting yourself confidently] **do** a sign of brilliance?　←　*nonsensical question*

Now the example is grammatical, but it still doesn't make any sense, because *do* is the wrong verb for a copular clause.

---

Now let's take a look at your full sentence, which we can regard as [a reduced form](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bconjunction-reduction%5d%20is%3aanswer)<sup>2</sup> of the following:

> ***Does** [presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas] a sign of brilliance
>   　or
>   <s>does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of</s> ignorance?

This is both nonsensical and ungrammatical.  However, with *is* it's grammatical and makes sense:

> **Is** [presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas] a sign of brilliance
>   　or
>   <s>is presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of</s> ignorance?

It's grammatical because *is* is an auxiliary and can invert with the subject, and it makes sense because *is* is the right verb to use in a  copular clause.

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup>Also called a **predicational copular clause**.
　<sup>2</sup>Basically, the repeated material has been deleted.
　<sup>3</sup>Verbs can be either auxiliary or lexical; auxiliaries can be modal or non-modal.

Symbols used in this answer:

<sup>#</sup> - nonsensical (wrong in terms of meaning, not grammar)
　* - ungrammatical

Answer (score 4):

**As written**, you need to use "is"

> Is presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of brilliance or ignorance?

Though, if these are two separate signs rather than requiring that they combine to form one giant sign, you'll want to use "are" instead.

> Are presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas signs of brilliance or ignorance?

You *can* use "does" but you need to change the sentence slightly. It requires a verb.

> Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas **convey** a sense of brilliance or ignorance?

I used "convey a sense" because it's idiomatic and is quite similar to "a sign".

You could also omit "a sign/sense of":

> Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas convey brilliance or ignorance?

To help in the future, consider simplifying the sentence:

> *Does it a sign of something?
>   Is it a sign of something?

Hopefully, this simpler version makes it clear that "does" in this form is incorrect.

Comment: Or to simplify the OP's question further in the 'does' format, I might prefer 'demonstrate' over 'convey': Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas *demonstrate* brilliance or ignorance?

Comment: Another possible choice of verb: Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas _signify_ brilliance or ignorance? Here _signify_ is used in the sense "to be a sign of".

Answer (score 1):

> (Does/is) presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of brilliance or ignorance? What verb to use?

There's one thing you should learn.*Does(do,did)* are used only when there is a verb in the sentence (but not "to be"). When it seems that there's no verb (but it should be)you add a copula verb "to be".

> [Is (a copula verb)] [presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas (a subject)][a sign of brilliance or ignorance (a subject complement)]?

Another example is

> Is this man a teacher?

The affirmative sentence would look as

> [Presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas (a subject)] [is (a copula verb)] [a sign of brilliance or ignorance (a subject complement)]

Answer (score 0):

> Does presenting yourself confidently and believing in your own ideas a sign of brilliance or ignorance?

can be simplified to:

> Does [something] a sign of [something else].

Now, it is obvious, that correct form is:

> Is [something] a sign of [something else].

In the example you are missing a verb. Better question is:

> Does [something] make an impression of [something else].

where *make* is the missing verb and "[Something] makes an impression of [something else]" is the (gamatically) correct answer. "[Something] a sign of [something else]" is not gramatically correct.

Answer (score -1):

Simple rules:

If the question starts with “is”, use the “+ing” form of the verb, or an adjective

- Is it raining?
- Is she clever?
- Are they running?
- Is he sick?

If the question starts with “do” or “does” you should use the simple form of the verb
- Does she know what is wrong?
- Do you think it is too expensive?
- Does he go to the gym?
In the question, it is correct grammatically to ask BOTH ways:

- Does anyone know why the system is down?
- Is anyone knowing why the system is down? (though this is an unusual way to ask)

Comment: No native speaker would say "Is anyone knowing why the system is down?".